# Does the term USING in the sentence act as gerund or participle?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbials, grammatical-roles, gerund-phrases, gerunds-vs-participles

> Whether they are good or bad, we can draw a comparison using their behaviour!

Is *using* a gerund/present participle in this sentence?

Comment: It's a verb and that's all you need to know! Modern grammar doesn't distinguish gerunds and present participles, but simply lumps both _ing_ forms together, calling them 'gerund-participles'.

Comment: Here's a **useful tool**: *Can you take the phrase and make a sentence beginning with it*? Like this: "Using their behavior may be useful as an example". So, a gerund-participle phrase used as a **subject**.

Comment: _Gerund_ is a special term reserved for participial clauses that are used as nouns (subject or object, generally). _Participle_ is the name for two English verb forms - the _-ing_ form (aka "the present active participle"), and "the perfect passive participle", which is the third principal part of the verb: _live/lived, show/shown, eat/eaten, set/set_. Some people refer to gerund or participle clauses as "phrases", since they often are missing subjects, or even for short as "gerunds" and "participles", but the distinctions are confusing and many people are confused.

Comment: Is what you're really asking here whether the non-finite clause *using their behavior* is (1) a second object argument to the  verb *draw*, or whether it's (2) a modifier of some other syntactic constituent such as the existing verb or object? Have you considered whether there might be an elided or assumed preposition such as *by* governing it?

Comment: ... and in this particular sentence, _using their behaviour,_ is definitely **not** a gerund, because it's not used as a noun, but rather as an adverb. That's one of the most frequent uses of participial phrases.

Comment: We can leave the house eating pretzels.

Answer (score 0):

> Whether they are good or bad, we can draw a comparison using their behaviour!

If you are in a learning environment where this is important then it will help to add the preposition "by":

= Whether they are good or bad, we can draw a comparison **by** *[the means of]* using their behaviour!

(You will be aware that a preposition + noun/substantive phrase results in a modifier.)

In this context, "**by** *[the means of]* using their behaviour" and "using their behaviour" are semantically identical.

*using their behaviour* is a gerund phrase = *using the action of their behaviour*

"[by] using their behaviour" is thus an adverbial modifier.

Comment: Yes, it's a type of means (or instrument) adjunct. But if there's no "by" present, it can hardly be a PP. "Using their behaviour" is thus simply a gerund-participial clause (not a PP) functioning as a modifier in clause structure.

Comment: Yes, looking again, I see that it is unclear: I have amended it.